# how to check if a php variable containing an ip address, lies in the range of two ip addresses in inet_aton format

Tags: php, mysql

[Query picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8vL3.png)I have a table called blacklisted, having columns start_ip & end_ip, i need to check if my variable $stat_ip(another column from a table called Hasoffers) lies between the range i.e is greater than or equal to start_ip and less than or equal to last_ip, using a mysql query. My query goes like this $result=mysql_query("Select inet_aton(network_start_ip),inet_aton(network_last_ip) from blacklisted where '".$stat_ip."' BETWEEN  inet_aton(network_start_ip) AND inet_aton(network_last_ip)"). This does returns a 0 count, which is not the expected output. Help on mysql query is appreciated.

```
<?php
include('adodb/adodb.inc.php');
$link=mysql_connect("166.26.18.122","vcc","abcd1234");
mysql_select_db("vcc");
$pl=mysql_query("SELECT stat_ip fromHasoffers");
$count=mysql_num_rows($pl);

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pl))
{
$stat_ip=$row['stat_ip'];
echo ip($stat_ip)."<br>";
$ip_Num=ip2long($stat_ip);
}

function blacklisted($ip_Num)
{
    $result=mysql_query("Select inet_aton(network_start_ip),inet_aton(network_last_ip) from blacklisted where '".$ip_Num."' BETWEEN  inet_aton(network_start_ip) AND inet_aton(network_last_ip)");
    $count=mysql_num_rows($result);


  return $count;

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to do inet_aton on your from Hasoffers query. like this

```
$pl=mysql_query("SELECT inet_aton(stat_ip) from Hasoffers");
$count=mysql_num_rows($pl);
```

without doing inet_aton $stat_ip has value with dots. e.g. 192.168.0.1

so your second query is like

```
Select inet_aton(network_start_ip),inet_aton(network_last_ip) from blacklisted where '192.168.0.1' BETWEEN  inet_aton(network_start_ip) AND inet_aton(network_last_ip)
```

In short change the first query and hopefully it will fix your problem.

## UPDATE

As you said you can't change your query.
try this

```
$pl=mysql_query("SELECT stat_ip from Hasoffers");    
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($pl))
{
$stat_ip=$row['stat_ip'];
echo ip($stat_ip)."<br>";
//for converting to LongInt
$ip_Num=ip2long($stat_ip);

} 
// Now pass $ip_Num instead of $stat_ip in your function 
function blacklisted($ip_Num)
```

Comment: I cannot change my query, since i need the $stat_ip in the ip4 format for some other function as well, so if could do something like $stat_ip=$row['inet_aton(stat_ip)'], or anything else you can suggest

Comment: This would just replace the dot (.) from the ip, however the inet_aton converts the ip into int format. How is that supposed to work.

Comment: @AasthaKathuria converting IP into long will do by using this function 
[http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php)

Comment: I did what you said, changed the variable to $ip_Num in my query too, still the count is zero. Can you check if the query is right. I edited my above code.

Comment: @AasthaKathuria Please put or die(mysql_error()); at the end of query to check what is the error.

Comment: @AasthaKathuria please remove single quotes around  91034526 from your query pic. you are forgetting its a integer and not a string. may after that it will work

Answer (score 1):

you can ip2long(ipaddress) function insted of below line

```
        **$ip_Num=str_replace('.','',$stat_ip);**
```

**ip2long** is working line **inet_aton()** mysql function.**ip2long** is a php function
eg:

$ip = '10.0.5.9';
printf("%u\n", ip2long($ip));

167773449

Comment: ip2long thing works, but the query return zero count. Can you check on the query.

Comment: send me the screen shot of your db data

Comment: what all do you need to see ?

Comment: $select_query = "Select inet_aton(network_start_ip),inet_aton(network_last_ip) from blacklisted where '".$ip_Num."' BETWEEN  inet_aton(network_start_ip) AND inet_aton(network_last_ip)"  ; echo $res; //send me this query

Comment: This query returns an empty set, which is my question.

Comment: SELECT *
FROM TABLE_NAME
WHERE (INET_ATON($stat_ip) BETWEEN INET_ATON(ipStart) AND INET_ATON(ipEnd)); //once try  like this